# Is there a way to set the chunk paths at runtime?

Tags: webpack

Say my current webpack configuation spits out some named chunks:

```
vendor.js
app.js
subapp1.js
subapp2.js
subapp3.js
```

When my chunks are deployed to our CDN, they get renamed and placed in a folder based off their md5 hash:

```
http://mycdn.com/99/02B0B8CBA2C6CBE524389E01C7769B-vendor.js
http://mycdn.com/14/99B792BDBA5C482F64F47CAE0531F7-app.js
http://mycdn.com/CF/AB0A6501A837EC4FAD5856DF15D290-subapp1.js
http://mycdn.com/78/69641FEC5DFB45B833DDBA1BAD0586-subapp2.js
http://mycdn.com/E7/E71E48B4FB598FB24BB530B6AE065E-subapp3.js
```

I know what these urls are at runtime, but I don't know how to tell webpack where to find them. I know I can use `__webpack_public_path__` to set `http://mycdn.com`, but how can I set the rest of the individual chunk paths accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the [chunk-manifest-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/diurnalist/chunk-manifest-webpack-plugin) provides a way to accomplish this.